# Create PostGreSQL schema and add tables

Tags: postgresql, web, yii2

I want to make graphic installer that asks user few questions and then creates schema and populates it with tables. I Will use [yii\db\Command's createTable()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-command.html#createTable()-detail) to create tables but I wonder how can I add new schema to the database before connecting to add tables.

I was thinking about Postgresql's [Create schema](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createschema.html) that I will run as raw command to DAO something like

```
Yii::$app->db->createCommand('CREATE SCHEMA schema_name')->execute();
```

but am not sure if it will work given `Yii::$app->db` is connected in another schema and I'm not Postgresql expert.

So I need help to know if that will work or even if there is a better way to solve my problem.

Comment: you cant create a schema in another database while connected to a different one. Perhaps issue the commands within a db_link https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/dblink.html

Comment: I want to create schema in the same database (so I believe I don't need to open the connection)